# reading the json array of HashMap<MyCustomeClass> in ajax

Tags: java, json, ajax

we have a Hashmap and converted that in to json object.

json Object we receive is :

```
{
"1": {
    "serverName": "abc"
     }
 }
```

we want to read the above response using `$.ajax` in jsp page. 
when we try to read it, getting the `error "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing` ) after argument list" in browser console,

code snippet where we getting the error

```
 $.ajax({
          type : 'POST',
          contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          url : 'MyServices1.do',
          success : function(datas) {
            alert(datas);
            var graphData = JSON.parse(datas);

            alert(graphData.1.serverName);  
          }  
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
alert(graphData.1.serverName);
```

throws the error since you can't access the property `1` directly. Instead use

```
alert(graphData[1].serverName);
```

Comment: But what if we don't know the key (here is "1") of the json object

Comment: @anjalijain you can iterate over the keys with `for (var k in graphData)  {...graphData[k]... }`